# VoIP certificate doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, certificate, voip

My iOS app wants to use VoIP, therefore I created VoIP certificate as described in Apple documentation. But, notifications don't work. I thought, that problem is in code, but when I substituted bundle id in Xcode and created new VoIP certificate - notifications got work. Why my previous bundle with certificate don't work? P.S. I uploaded my app to iTunes Connect, does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

If your app uploaded on App store with normal push notification certificate then yes it will matter a lot.

Because certificate and token differ for normal push notification and push kit silent notification.

Integrating push kit step by step.

- Certificate process is there.
- Payload form is there.
- iOS ( Swift/Objective C code is there)
- Debug methond are there

Please do refer.

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Comment: I uploaded new version to test flight, but VoIP still doesn't work. why?

Comment: Previous versions used normal pushes, but now we want to substitute it bu VoIP. How can we do that?